# What makes Gold so different from Platinum?

Tags: electronic-configuration

Looking at Wikipedia, Gold & Platinum are in adjacent seats.

```
    Platinum                                Gold
[Xe] 4f14 5d9 6s1                     [Xe] 4f14 5d10 6s1
Atomic number of 78                   Atomic number of 79  
Atomic pass of 195.084u               Atomic mass of 196.96657 ± 0.000004 u
```

How does that single electron make such a huge difference?

Comment: From the electronic configuration, (and therefore the spatial organization of the AO's), it has to be known that "filling" or "non-filling" electrons play the role inside the Binding energy of the atoms, for an exquisite example the fact that *Why is mercury liquid at room T°?* depends only on the position of the electrons, and so the accesible quantum states for the binding.

Comment: The difference is of a single electron if you consider only one atom. 1g of gold has about 3 followed by 21 zeros more electrons than Platinum, and if that's not much of a difference for you...

Comment: Let's not forget that the number of electrons is not the **only** difference in the subatomic particles of Pt and Au.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the asker is referring to when they mention the "huge difference". Arguably, gold and platinum are actually strikingly similar, even in their oddities (such as relativistic effects); if you want a huge difference, why not compare neighbours such as C and N, or among the metals, Cu and Zn? There are plenty more dissimilar pairs without invoking a fundamental change in electron distribution (like going on to the next subshell). So what exactly *is* the huge difference in question?

Answer (score 1):

That one electron is making sure that Gold has a complete d-orbital, and therefor is much more stable. Elements want to achieve noble gas configurations, and if they can't, then they want to have a half-filled orbitals. In the case of gold the d-orbital is filled completely and the s-orbital is half filled. Whereas Platinum doesn't have that complete d-orbital filled.

**Chemical properties (such as reactivity) are influenced by electrons.** The amount of neutrons will determine if it can be radioactive or not(,...) look at Tritium : that is a hydrogen atom with 2 neutrons in it and it is radioactive. Whilst protium (the most common isotope of Hydrogen with 1 proton and 0 neutrons) is not radioactive.